# React native component does not update

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a problem with react native that I can't understand, I probably have a wrong approach.

So I have this component, basically is a menu and when i click an item I call handleClick.

```
class Header extends Component {
  //constructor and ecc....

  handleClick = (flow) => {
    navigate('Category', {catId: flow})   
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <View>  
        {this.state.menu.map(menuSingle => (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.handleClick(menuSingle.object_id)} >
              <Text>{menuSingle.title }</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))} 
      </View>
    );
  }  
}
export default Header;
```

Then in Category.js I get data by id from the menu but if use the menu form home.js component it's working, but the same menu when i use it in category.js does not update the state.

```
class Category extends Component{ 
  //constructor ecc... 

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch("url="+parseInt(this.state.catId))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((posts) => {
        this.setState({
          posts: posts,
          loading: false
        }, function(){
         });
      })
       .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
       });
  }

  render() {  
    if(this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <Text> Loading...</Text>
      )
    }

    return (
      <SafeAreaView >
        <Header/>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.posts.map(post => (
            <View>
              <Text> {post.title} </Text>
            </View>  
          ))} 
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Category;
```

Any advice on how to recall the same component or update the category state from the menu component?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) example for this type of question

Comment: have you tried adding forceUpdate to the callback of setState ? That might narrow down where the problem is

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan do you mean in componentDidMount?

Comment: `this.setState({
          posts: posts,
          loading: false
        }, () => this.forceUpdate());`